# Ipad image size and resolutions?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

Hi which are the image size and resolutions needed for an ipad, iphone retina and non retina launch icons and tab navigation icons? is there a guide of icons size and resolution???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a web site that looks useful: [iOS Resolution Quick Reference](http://www.iosres.com)

There is also this comprehensive table in the [Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconMatrix.html).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there's a huge table for iOS and Android icon sizes on [this website](http://www.gieson.com/Library/projects/utilities/icon_slayer/#.Un5pF5RMTe5) if you scroll down a bit. Theres also a handy icon maker. (Where you put in an image and it generates all the icons you need)